# Animation button custom ListView issue

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-listview

I use a custom listview to show a list of item, each item is an instance of my object with a button on it. I set an ValueAnimator for button of some item have attribute isAnim = true. It seem ok but when i scroll listview down, some of item with 'isAnim = false' also animate.
Here my code animation:

```
protected void blinkblinkImage(Button bt) {

    ValueAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(bt, "textColor", activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white),
                                                    activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.cam),
                                                    activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue1),
                                                    activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.red),
                                                    activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
    colorAnim.setDuration(300);
    colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    colorAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    colorAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
    colorAnim.start();

}
```

And here is set animation for item

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    if(convertView == null)
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_xe, null);
    final Button btTT = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt_tt);

    final HashMap<String, String> itemxe = data.get(position);

    final Boolean isAnim = itemxe.get(Login_Activity.TAG_ANIM);


    if(isAnim)
        blinkblinkImage(btTT);


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
  protected void blinkblinkImage(Button bt) {

    ValueAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(bt, "textColor", activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white),
                                                    activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.cam),
                                                    activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue1),
                                                    activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.red),
                                                    activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));

    bt.setHasTransientState(true);
    colorAnim.setDuration(300);
    colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    colorAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    colorAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
    colorAnim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter{
    @Overrid 
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation){

         bt.setHasTransientState(false);
    }

    });
    colorAnim.start();

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it work. Hmm, but setHasTransientState only avaiable in api 16 and higher

Comment: So use [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) instead.